# How to index data to specific cluster in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm researching Remote Clusters of Elastic at the moment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-remote-clusters.html Can anyone advise if it is possible to specify cluster while indexing data to Elastic?

Right now I found only cross-cluster search approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-cluster "search" is only for seamlessly searching across different clusters through a single central cluster.

Write and indexing operations still have to be directed to each cluster specifically, there's no such thing as cross-cluster "indexing", i.e. your indexing client must point to the cluster into which the data should be indexed.